# Add button is not calling colorselector through wapper append

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add colorbutton through add button, and I am using append method of jQuery, but its not calling `COLORSELECTOR()`. Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
$('#colorselector').colorselector();

$(document).ready(function () {
    var max_fields = 10;
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button");

    var x = 1;

    $(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<section id="colorselectors"><div class="bs-docs-example"><select id="colorselector" name="c_picker[]"><option value="106" data-color="#A0522D">sienna</option><option value="47" data-color="#CD5C5C" selected="selected">indianred</option><option value="87" data-color="#FF4500">orangered</option><option value="17" data-color="#008B8B">darkcyan</option></select><a href="#" class="remove_field"><h5>Remove</h5></a>&nbsp;</div></section>');
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    });
});
</script>


<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Colors</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thje issue is that when you dynamically add the button, you have not initialized `.colorselector()` to that new element. You will also want to make sure each ID is unique.

Comment: That sounds interesting, how to do that in this case? Can you help by editing code if possible. Please. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button");
  var x = 1;

  add_button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      x++;
      wrapper.append('<section id="colorselector-' + x + '"><div class="bs-docs-example"><select id="colorselector" name="c_picker[]"><option value="106" data-color="#A0522D">sienna</option><option value="47" data-color="#CD5C5C" selected="selected">indianred</option><option value="87" data-color="#FF4500">orangered</option><option value="17" data-color="#008B8B">darkcyan</option></select><a href="#" class="remove_field"><h5>Remove</h5></a>&nbsp;</div></section>');
      $("#colorselector-" + x).colorselector();
    }
  });

  wrapper.on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  });

  $('#colorselector').colorselector();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Colors</button>
</div>
```

Since you're appending new HTML, you then need to initialize it just like you would the first element:

```
$("#colorselector-" + x).colorselector();
```

You can see in the `if()`, when the new element is created, I created a unique ID so it can be easily selected.

Comment: Awesome, That worked my friend,, Thank you so much for your help..Appreciate it.